# Apache versions conflict

Tags: php, apache

I would like to set up Apache and PHP, but I think that, I have two versions of Apache, which is causing a conflict.

(I couldn't find a topic with the same problem, so If you have solved this problem before, please let me know the links. thanks)

I have OS X and If I run **$ httpd -v** I have Server version: **Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)** and for PHP **$ php -v** I got
**PHP 7.0.12**

If I test in my browser just **localhost** it displayed "it works!

If I open the file *sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf* and activate (uncomment) the php module, I have this 
**LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so** (I uncommented the line)

Shouldn't be php7?

Additionally, If I open the file **index.html** located in *cd /Library/WebServer/Documents* and add the lines

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>It works!</h1>
<?php
$x = "Hello world!";
$y = 'Hello world!';

echo $x;
echo "<br>";
echo $y;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and test again **localhost** in my browser, it only displays *It works!*

But If I select manually and open the file **index.html** under /*Library/WebServer/Documents* I got this:

```
It works!
"; echo $y; ?>
```

In this case PHP is not activated.

Could you please tell me, how to work with the right Apache 2.4 with PHP (version 7)

P.D. I know that another alternative is to use MAMP, but I would like to fix this issue becuase I wouldn't like to have other conflicts due to it

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're using the install of Apache that came with your mac. That's not really what we usually do. I would suggest that you check out this article and get yourself set up with nginx/php-fpm, that's probably more like what you'll want to deploy to production. Having a local env that matches dev/prod as closely as possible is really helpful. https://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/

Comment: yes, I'm using Apache from my mac, at the beginning I wanted to download Apache from https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/ , but I found it quite difficult through that way, but I will look at the link. Thank you!

Comment: The article I posted walks you through php 5.6...you can dig a little to find instructions for php7. Like this: https://medium.com/grav-with-brandr/brewing-nginx-and-php7-for-grav-development-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-bf54237a6327#.p8whzwh03

The cool kids are using Docker for this these days. It's a little more to set up...but it's way better, gives you a lot more control over your development environment on a per project basis.

Comment: Thank you again!, first I would like to set up apache and php, later on I could look Docker in detail. If I have again problems, I will let you know ;)

Comment: Sure...check this out for Apache: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: yes, I actually I tried it, but if i remember correctly I had some problems with brew, I need to try again, because I have been trying in many ways, and in one of them, I have problems with the Xcode licence, but now I looked at your post https://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/ , so now I'm installing Xcode, then I will proceed again with brew

Comment: @jcorry , I just finished the Xcode installation but I got this message "The system extension "VBoxDrv.kext" is not compatible with this version of OS X and can’t be used" you think that could impact somehow?

Comment: Uh oh...which OS X and Xcode versions...I assumed Sierra and current Xcode

Comment: yes, both are current versions

Comment: @jcorry, I hope you can help me, I followed again every step from https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions After creating my "Sites Folder" and adding the dummy content "My User Web Root", I restarted apache sudo apachectl -k restart and I got this: httpd not running, trying to start
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 14219 Segmentation fault: 11  $HTTPD "$@"  is there a way I could show you the httpd.conf file?

Comment: What do apache logs say?

Comment: @jcorry , here you can see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424127/apache-version-conflict-cont

Comment: Did you turn off web sharing and stop the OS X apache? Look in activity monitor and see if there are any httpd processes running.

Comment: it seems that is working now, but I couldn't activate php. I installed it, but when I wanted to activate it inside the httpd.conf file the PHP module was not displayed