# Apache version conflict (cont)

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf

Concerning the post [Apache versions conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416622/apache-versions-conflict?noredirect=1#comment70048905_41416622). I tried again the installation of apache following the steps from https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

I still have some problems if I want to test **localhost** from my local **Site** folder.

Result of apache log

[image]

Regarding the error

> Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
>   using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName'...

I tried the option of adding **ServerName localhost** in the file */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* https://askubuntu.com/questions/454497/apache2-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name but I don't know if that is that is the right file, because i'm working with apache 2.4 (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf)

Additionally, if I run the command ***sudo apachectl -k restart*** I got this

```
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

In my file ***/etc/apache2/httpd.conf***

I have this:

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User amhg
Group staff

# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot /Users/amhg/Sites
<Directory /Users/amhg/Sites>

  #
    AllowOverride All
```

and I uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so`

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can see all of your apache installed version with command :

```
rpm -qa | grep httpd
```

in your log file I do not see any error.

can you sent all of your log file?

and can you explain what do you see in browser when go to :

http://localhost

Comment: Thank you @elham_jahan for your reply, at the end I decided to switch to MAMP, I think it is better to start with it as a beginer.